# Symbolize iOS Crashlog without Archive

Tags: ios, crash-dumps

I have an application crashlog on my development device (with the store version of an app). Bad thing is that I don't have the archived version at hand.

Is there a way I can symbolize against an old svn revision which matches the store version (approximately)?

Just running `symbolicatecrash` gives the warning:

```
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /var/mobile/Applications/...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have the dsym file (part of the archive) to symbolicate the report.  The old SVN revision doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Thought so, too bad. Maybe I can reproduce the error on the current development revision.